# Finding a trapping region for the Hénon map

Tags: dynamical-systems

In his famous paper [A two-dimensional mapping with strange attractor](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103900150), Hénon gives an explicit trapping region for the [Hénon map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9non_map) with $a=1.3$ and $b=0.4$.

In the figure below, the quadrilateral $Q=ABCD$ is mapped to the curvilinear quadrilateral $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ which is totally contained in $Q$. Therefore, all orbits of the Hénon map starting in $Q$ remain in $Q$. It is in this sense that $Q$ is a trapping region for the map. Hénon gives explicit coordinates for the points $A,B,C,D$.

How did Hénon find the quadrilateral $Q$ explicitly?

How does one find an explicit trapping region for other values of the map parameters $a$ and $b$?

Are there any other large quadrilaterals or triangles that are trapping regions for the Hénon map?

[image]

(Picture from the book "Chaotic evolution and strange attractors" by Ruelle)

Comment: Related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319302/what-is-a-trapping-region and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2962375/strategy-for-finding-trapping-region-of-a-discrete-dynamical-system-hénon-map

Comment: In the paper [Characteristic exponents and strange attractors](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01940767), Feit seems to describe a more complicated trapping region in the general case

Comment: There are other trapping regions. When you numerically compute the basin of attraction of the attractor and the attractor itself you can get very good guesses for trapping regions.

Comment: @SillyMathematician, any references for explicit trapping regions? Thanks.

Comment: @lhf Can any one help me : The group of bijection $G$ of the set $X=\{1, 2,3,..,n\}$ where $n\ge 3$ acts on $S$ via $i\to f(i)$ . Then find the number of orbits of the natural action of $G$ on $X×X×X$ defined by $f•(i, j, k) =(f(I), f(j), f(k)) $