# Henon map and its parameter analysis

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I am trying to create an encryption algorithm for educational purpose. Where I use Henon map to encrypt a message. In the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9non_map) section I got, **"The map depends on two parameters, $a$ and $b$, which for the classical Hénon map have values of $a = 1.4$ and $b = 0.3$"**

And I use that value, which seems OK. But is there any range where the chaotic nature hold? How to predict the range?

Another question is, how to pick initial guess $(x_0,y_0)$ for that map? Is there any dependency between their initial guess with the values of $a,b$? I am asking because some of random initial guess give me `OverflowError` in python code. One more thing, how to check sensitivity of Henon map for a small change in key $(a,b)$ or $(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: For choosing starting points whose orbits remain bounded, use a trapping region. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4063271/finding-a-trapping-region-for-the-hénon-map

Comment: Thanks for the link, @lhf. But those seem heavy mathematics for me now. I need an answer which is accessible for beginner, like only mention the range explicitly with some insight. Thanks again.